# 3D body plot in matlab ( volume visualization )

Tags: matlab

I have little or no experience with volumetric data in MATLAB, 
I need to complete next task:
I have 3 vectors ( rows ):

```
x_ = vector(1:smpl:max_row,1);

y_ = vector(1:smpl:max_row,2);

z_ = vector(1:smpl:max_row,3);
```

that are samples from large 3 columns array  vector with height max_row.
x_ , y_ , z_ are points of 3D figure - surface points of the figure ( volume ). They represent 3D body that should be drawn in matlab.

I created linear grid:

```
%linear grid

a = -1.1:step:(-1.1+step*(length(x_)-1));

b = -1.1:step:(-1.1+step*(length(y_)-1));

c = -1.1:step:(-1.1+step*(length(z_)-1));


[x,y,z] = meshgrid(-1.1:step:(-1.1+step*(length(x_)-1)));
```

and also I create array v length(x_)*length(x_)*length(x_) that contains '1'  in cells that are of 3D body representation function points and '0' another.

I tryied to make interpolation:

```
vi = interp3(x,y,z,v,x,y,z,'nearest');
```

but then vi = v that I've already created.

Now I need to plot the v array on 3D and form 3D body like in

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isonormals.html

for example.

I make that next way:

```
%plotting:

figure

p = patch(isosurface(x,y,z,v,1e-5,'verbose'),'FaceColor','green','EdgeColor','none');

grid on;

isonormals(v,p);

daspect([1 1 1])

view(3); 

axis tight;

camproj perspective;

camlight

lighting gouraud

colormap(hsv)
```

but I get then only small rectangles in place of function '1' that are not connected like in picture that is attached.
I expect solid body enclosed by that points to be plotted.

Does anybody know what is the problem , how to draw 3D body from the x,y,z,v arrays ?

Thanks in advance.

image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JZiK.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which will be a nice plot (it interpolates a bit though):

```
x = vector(1:smpl:max_row,1);
y = vector(1:smpl:max_row,2);
z = vector(1:smpl:max_row,3);

% Settings
displaySurface = 1;
displayPoints = 0;
xres = 800; % Resolution, the higher, the smoother
yres = 800;         
cm = 'default'; % Colormap

% Axes Limits
xmin = min(x); 
ymin = min(y);
xmax = max(x); 
ymax = max(y); 
xi = linspace(xmin, xmax, xres);
yi = linspace(ymin, ymax, yres);

% Figure
myfig = figure('Position', [200 200 800 600]);

rotate3d off
[XI, YI] = meshgrid(xi, yi);
ZI = griddata(x, y, z, XI, YI, 'cubic');
mesh(XI,YI,ZI);
colormap(cm)

if(displaySurface == 1)
    hold on;
    surf(XI, YI, ZI, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
end
hold on;
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y'); 
zlabel('z'); 
title('Title', 'FontWeight', 'bold');
xlim([xmin xmax])
ylim([ymin ymax])
grid off;

if(displayPoints == 1)
    hold on
    plot3(x, y, z,'marker','p','markerfacecolor','w','linestyle','none')
    hidden off 
end
```

Comment: Hi Col Heather, Thank you for your the proposition for solution. I tried your code , look what I get for my current data : http://fileslap.com/94t/forum_plot ; I need something another - solid body enclosed by the points X,Y,Z . Look at this : ( exactly what should be drawn) :http://fileslap.com/94s/plot_ .  I am continuing to solve the issue. I hope you'll help...

Comment: Good question, I think you should only plot the points of the 'REAL' body without all those high-level-curves (those can be created by using `contour`). This really should work if you have enough points for the main part of the body :)

Comment: Hi, yes the question is how to plot the body ( smooth ) enclosed by the points as at the pictures but your code plots nice , smooth but surface and not a 3D enclosed volume. I think triangulation should be considered. I recently tryied delaunay it draws very close but yet not smooth .How to plot volume from that points and not a surface ?